# What kind of memory DIMM for Dell Vostro 3670

Tags: memory, dell-vostro

I want to add some memory to my Dell Vostro 3670 running an Intel i5-8400. At neither Crucial nor Kingston do I find the Vostro 3670 listed.

What kind of memory should I get?

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of memory should I get?

The Dell Vostro 3670 comes with 8 GB DDR4 but there are other configuration possibilities.  You have a Core i5-8400, which is a desktop processor, so you want to purchase DDR4 for a desktop.  The other processor configurations are also desktop processors.  The maximum amount of memory it supports is 32 GB.  It supports 2666 MHz DDR4 Non-ECC modules. The other processors support a different memory frequency, checking the specifications for your particular configuration, is highly recommended

[Specifications](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/vostro-3670-desktop_owners-manual3_en-us.pdf#page12)

[Manual](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ar/en/arbsdt1/vostro-3670-desktop/vostro_3670_setup_and_specs/set-up-your-computer?guid=guid-7a6b47c6-cbcb-4b7c-a691-40179bce6d9b&lang=en-us)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the memory specs for your model.

So they are udimm memory modules (you have 2 module slots) at various sizes (GB) and speeds (Mhz)

[Your support page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/vostro-3670-desktop/manuals)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use a scanner like the one at Crucial to get your current specs (link below). 
http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner

Alternatively, the instructions at the link below will show your current specs.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/66809-determine-system-memory-size-speed-type-windows-10-a.html

From this info, you'll see that for a laptop, you likely have two banks, each occupied. You'll need to swap them both out for replacement. You likely want a pair of modules in the same form factor as your existing, capacity depending on the maximum the motherboard can handle (need more research there, likely 4Gb or 8Gb each). You'll want a clock speed equal or greater than your current. Remember, the bus sets the speed so you need to support at least that speed or exceed it with your selection. 1) Form factor 2) Capacity 3) Speed. Physically swapping them will be something for the Dell website, keep all contact surfaces clean and untouched by grubby fingers, and make sure the modules are firmly 'seated' in the bays before replacing the cover. Good luck